# Embedding Youtube video covers other divs

Tags: html, css, youtube

On my site there is a static div which functions as a header. Where there is a youtube video also on the page and the user scrolls down, the youtube video covers the header, even though it has a much lower z-index value.

How can this be rectified so that the embedded video appears below the header at all times?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had this problem myself a while back.

You need to add a wmode parameter with the value of opaque, ie `wmode="opaque"`

Answer (score 1):

[Possible Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10403124/1411473)

Anyways, I checked my code, and I added this:

```
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
<embed [whatever you have here] wmode="transparent" />
```

in your `<object>`.

Hope that works for you, I remember where I originally got this from said to add a z-index of 1 to the containing div as well, although I did not (maybe to work in IE or something).

**Edit:** If your instead using an iframe version for it, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5281002/1411473) looks promising.